# 2 pow X using large integers

Tags: c

I am having a bit of problem with my assignment. The user enters X (an integer 1 <= x <= 10000). I then have to work out the power of 2 with x, add all the digits of the answer together and output it to the user. So for example if the user enters 4 is would be 2^4 = 16. 1+6 = 7. However this doesn't work with large integers because 2^10000 is too big to store so I'm assuming I have to use an array.

I get the concept, I just have to keep doubling 2 'x' times to get the answer, but I don't know how to store it in an array and how to deal with when say 8 is doubled you get 16, with long multiplication you need carries don't you?

Would be thankful of any help received.

So overall my question is:

1. How to read the input of X. Do I `scanf("%s")` and store in an array?
2. Once stored, how do I go about doubling (as the base will always be 2)

Comment: Have you considered using a so-called bignum library, such as the [GNU multiple precision arithmetic library](http://gmplib.org/)?

Comment: Those are two separate questions that you should ask separately.

Comment: I am not allowed to use a bignum library unfortunately

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag it accordingly. Hint: if all you need to do is print the number, you don't actually need to store the whole thing in memory. You just need to find the decimal representation of 2^x.

Comment: Note this [meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123758/can-we-now-burninate-the-homework-tag-and-discourage-its-use) on the homework tag.

Comment: Removed the tag, @pmjordan - The task is to work out the pow then add the digits of the result together the print to the user.

Comment: The range of `x` is very small. You can put all the answers in your source (it will take around 50kb) and just print the correct one for given `x`.

Comment: @Ninefingers sorry, I didn't realise there had been a change in policy on Homework questions

Comment: @pmjordan it's not really official yet; I'm just trying to discourage its usage as the tag makes little difference. But feel free to disagree on meta :)

Comment: @Ninefingers I don't have the energy or time to engage in the meta debates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.
Reading the input shouldn't be a problem. As you know that 1 <= x <= 10000, you can read it as usual: `scanf("%d", &x);`.

2.
As you're not allowed to use a bignum library, why not make one yourself? You can store a big number digit by digit in an array of `int`s or `char`s. Start with something like this:

```
int product[100] = { 1 };
```

That is, you're storing 2^0 = 1 in the product initially. Then you can carry out the multiplication left-to-right: multiply each element of `pruduct` by 2, modulo 10. If a carry occurs, add that to the next element.

When you're done, find out the most significant digit searching right to left. Then reverse the digits, or just print them in reverse order. You can also use a marker to the most significant end. Whenever a carry out occurs in the most significant digit, the marker will be incremented.

The array size may be reduced by storing multiple digits per element, say, 6 digits per element. Then you'll need to multiply each element by 2, modulo 1000000.

The code would be something like this:

```
for(p = 0; p < x; p++)
{
    carry = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        z = product[i] * 2 + carry;
        product[i] = z % 10;
        carry = z / 10;
    }
}

for(i = 99; product[i] == 0; i--);
for(; i >= 0; i++)
    printf("%d", product[i]);
```

Comment: When you say multiply each element of product by 2, modulo 10. Would I be doing that on one line? e.g. in a for loop until X. product[i] = product[i] * 2 % 10

Comment: How big should I make my product array? If I want to store up to 10000 digits would the array be size 10000?

Comment: @Paul Of course! But if you want to make it dynamic (and if you're allowed to) you can use `vector` from STL. Or you can determine the size from some simple calculations.

Comment: One more problem and I think i'm finished. When I go to add the digits of the array together I keep getting random numbers back. E.g. if x = 4. I print the array and correctly get 16 (printing the array backwards). However when do this: for(i = 0; i < 3011; i++)
 {
  sum = sum + product[i];
 }

 printf("%d", sum); I get '1322076' instead of '7'. Any ideas?

Comment: Is `sum` initialized properly?

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't even notice that. Great! My program is fully working. Thanks so much for all your help FlopCoder!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need carries / an array to store large integers; that's how GMP works.

This isn't as hard to achieve as it sounds. When it comes to using assembly, specifically `x86`, there are even special instructions (`adc`, `sbc`) which set the carry flag (`CF`).

In C, you can't use these, unfortunately, however, this is what `GMP` does. As a set of hints, here's a few:

- `#include <stdint.h>` if available to you (C99) will give you the ability to guarantee the widths of your integers, e.g. `uint32_t`.
- This works:

  ```
  uint64_t x = (uint64_t) a + (uint64_t) b;
  ```

  Where a and b are `uint32_t`.
- If you think carefully about the above statement, you can extract the carry from `x` if you need to.
- For the storage of a large integer, in school you might have studied "hundreds, tens and units" i.e. the concept of filling up  a bucket until it reaches 10, then doing the carry. This is no different to doing the same thing with integers of size `2^32` except it seems a bit unnatural!
- Just like that, basic bignum operations involve treating each unit level separately.
- This is also known as arithmetic on a different base. Compare base 8 (octal numbers), base 16 (hex) with the concept of base 2^32.
- The types and sizes I'm using here might not work/be used in practice for performance reasons, but the concept holds.